# Azure Recognize_once_async().get() not receving input when running with my UI

Tags: python, azure, tkinter, speech-recognition, translation

The TLDR is that when translator.recognize_once_async().get() runs, it blocks my code which it should, however, no matter how much i speak into my microphone, it does not work.

ive tested this against the lab exercise, of which by itself it returns no errors and is capable of detecting an audio input. But when running with tkinter, it results in it refusing to accept any voice inputs and elapses the whole 15s.

Ive tried using thread and queue, thinking that this method would let me run the voice input detection in the background. However it still doesnt work.

I have checked my microphone input access and tested it against the exercise labs provided by azure

Following is the code i used to test it

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import time as timer
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speech_sdk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# note: dropdown boxes work fine in my code testing, but for code simplicity its preset to english input, chinese output

# initialize azure service
load_dotenv()
ai_key = os.getenv('SPEECH_KEY')
ai_region = os.getenv('SPEECH_REGION')

speech_config = speech_sdk.SpeechConfig(ai_key, ai_region)
# Configure translation
translation_config = speech_sdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(ai_key, ai_region)
translation_config.add_target_language('en')
translation_config.add_target_language('zh-Hans')
translation_config.add_target_language('ta')
translation_config.add_target_language('yue')
translation_config.add_target_language('ms')


def reset_application():
    # Reset the combobox values
    input_lang_combobox.set('')
    output_lang_combobox.set('')

    # Reset the combobox options to all languages
    input_lang_combobox['values'] = languages
    output_lang_combobox['values'] = languages

    # Reset the status label to its initial state
    status_label.config(text="Status: Waiting for both input and output language to be selected")
    # Re-enable the run button and disable it until new selections are made
    run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

def update_languages(*args):
    # Get the currently selected languages
    input_language = input_lang_combobox.get()
    output_language = output_lang_combobox.get()

    # Update output language options based on input selection
    if input_language:
        output_options = [lang for lang in languages if lang != input_language]
        output_lang_combobox['values'] = output_options
        if output_language == input_language:
            output_lang_combobox.set('')
    else:
        output_lang_combobox['values'] = languages

    # Update input language options based on output selection
    if output_language:
        input_options = [lang for lang in languages if lang != output_language]
        input_lang_combobox['values'] = input_options
        if input_language == output_language:
            input_lang_combobox.set('')
    else:
        input_lang_combobox['values'] = languages

    # Check if both languages are selected to update the status label and button state
    if input_language and output_language:
        style.configure('Custom.TButton', 
                        foreground='orange',  # Text color
                        background='white')  # Background color      
        status_label.config(text=f"Status: Ready to translate from {input_language} to {output_language}\n      "
                                    f"Click button to begin translation service",style='Custom.TButton')

        run_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)  # Enable the button
    else:
        status_label.config(text="Status: Waiting for both input and output language to be selected")
        run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)  # Keep the button disabled

def start_translation():
    global translation_config
    run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    # configure input language
    translation_config.speech_recognition_language = 'en-US'
    
    status_label.config(text="Status: Please speak into the microphone now")
    def translate(targetLanguage):

        def recognition(targetLanguage):
            global translation_config
            audio_config = speech_sdk.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
            translator = speech_sdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(translation_config, audio_config=audio_config)
            result = translator.recognize_once_async().get() #UI is supposed to be unresponsive when detecing input, but here it doesnt get any input back, elapsing the whole 15s
            print(result.text)
            print(result.translations['zh-Hans'])
            if result.reason == speech_sdk.ResultReason.TranslatedSpeech:
                root.after(1000, translate_process, targetLanguage, result)
            elif result.reason == speech_sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
                new_window2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
                new_window2.title("Error Pop-Up")
                translated_text_label = tk.Label(new_window2, text=f"Status: An error occurred {result.no_match_details}, event 'matching speech with input' failed. Restarting Process\nClose the pop-up to proceed", font=("Arial", 12,))
                translated_text_label.pack()
                reset_application()
            elif result.reason == speech_sdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
                cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
                new_window2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
                new_window2.title("Error Pop-Up")
                translated_text_label = tk.Label(new_window2, text=f"Status: An error occurred {cancellation_details.reason}, event 'input speech' failed. Restarting Process\nClose the pop-up to proceed", font=("Arial", 12,))
                translated_text_label.pack()
                reset_application()   

        def translate_process(targetLanguage,result):
            status_label.config(text="Status: Valid Input Speech Detected. Translating In Process")
            try:
                translation = result.translations[targetLanguage]
            except Exception as e:
                new_window2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
                new_window2.title("Error Pop-Up")
                translated_text_label = tk.Label(new_window2, text=f"Status: An error occurred: {e}, event 'Translation' failed. Restarting Process\nClose the pop-up to proceed", font=("Arial", 12,))
                translated_text_label.pack()
                reset_application()
            root.after(1000, complete_translation, targetLanguage, translation)

        def complete_translation(targetLanguage, translation):
            global speech_config
            status_label.config(text="Status: Translation Complete")

            # Synthesize translation
            voices = {
                "en": "en-SG-WayneNeural",
                "yue": "yue-CN-YunSongNeural",
                "ta": "ta-SG-AnbuNeural",
                "zh-Hans": "zh-CN-YunxiNeural",
                "ms": "ms-MY-OsmanNeural"
            }

            speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = voices.get(targetLanguage)
            speech_synthesizer = speech_sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config)
            root.after(1000, synthesize_output, translation, speech_synthesizer)

        def synthesize_output(translation, speech_synthesizer):
            status_label.config(text="Status: Producing Output")
            speak = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(translation).get()
            if speak.reason != speech_sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
                print(speak.reason)
            reset_application()

        # Start the translation after a short delay to allow the label to update
        root.after(500, recognition, targetLanguage)

    # Configure output language + begin translation
    translate(targetLanguage='zh-Hans')

languages = ["English", "Chinese", "Cantonese", "Malay", "Tamil"]

# Assuming root is your Tkinter root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x400")  # Adjust the size as needed

# Add the Translation App label at the top
app_title_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Translation App", font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 56, "bold"), foreground='orange')
app_title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, columnspan=2)  # Span across 2 columns if needed

# Dropdown Frame
dropdown_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
dropdown_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# Input Language ComboBox setup
input_lang_label = ttk.Label(dropdown_frame, text="Select Input Language", foreground="white",background="orange" ,font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 24, "bold"))
input_lang_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
input_lang_combobox = ttk.Combobox(dropdown_frame, values=languages)
input_lang_combobox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
input_lang_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', update_languages)

# Output Language ComboBox setup
output_lang_label = ttk.Label(dropdown_frame, text="Select Output Language", foreground="white",background="orange",font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 24, "bold"))
output_lang_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
output_lang_combobox = ttk.Combobox(dropdown_frame, values=languages)
output_lang_combobox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
output_lang_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', update_languages)

# Button Frame
button_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=30)

# Configure style for buttons
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Custom.TButton', foreground='orange', background='white', font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 12, "bold"), padding=10)

# Run and Reset Buttons
run_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Begin Translation", style='Custom.TButton', command=start_translation, state=tk.DISABLED)
run_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

reset_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Reset", style='Custom.TButton', command=reset_application)
reset_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

# Status Bar
status_bar = ttk.Frame(root, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
status_bar.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=20, pady=50)
status_label = ttk.Label(status_bar, text="Status: Waiting for both input and output language to be selected", anchor=tk.W)
status_label.pack(fill=tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Added a reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following sample code using tkinter to convert speech to text while speaking into my microphone.*

**Code :**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

class AudioToTextTranslator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Speech to Text Translator")

        dropdown_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
        dropdown_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        input_lang_label = ttk.Label(dropdown_frame, text="Select Input Language", foreground="white", background="orange", font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 24, "bold"))
        input_lang_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.input_lang_combobox = ttk.Combobox(dropdown_frame, values=list(languages.keys()))
        self.input_lang_combobox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
        self.input_lang_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.update_languages)

        output_lang_label = ttk.Label(dropdown_frame, text="Select Output Language", foreground="white", background="orange", font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 24, "bold"))
        output_lang_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.output_lang_combobox = ttk.Combobox(dropdown_frame, values=list(languages.keys()))
        self.output_lang_combobox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.output_lang_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.update_languages)

        button_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
        button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Custom.TButton', foreground='orange', background='white', font=("LG Smart UI Bold", 12, "bold"), padding=10)

        self.run_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Begin Translation", style='Custom.TButton', command=self.start_translation, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.run_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        self.reset_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Reset", style='Custom.TButton', command=self.reset_application)
        self.reset_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

    def update_languages(self, event):
        self.run_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def start_translation(self):
        output_language_code = languages[self.output_lang_combobox.get()]

        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="<speech_key>", region="<speech_region>")
        speech_config.speech_recognition_language = output_language_code

        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
        recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

        print("Listening for audio...")
        result = recognizer.recognize_once()

        if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized")
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))

    def reset_application(self):
        self.input_lang_combobox.current(0)
        self.output_lang_combobox.current(0)
        self.run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    languages = {"English": "en-US", "Chinese (Simplified)": "zh-CN", "Tamil": "ta-IN", "Malay": "ms-MY"}
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AudioToTextTranslator(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully, converting the speech translation to text output as shown below.

```py
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxx>python kam.py
Listening for audio...
Recognized: Hi Kamali. How are you?
Listening for audio...
Recognized: 嗨。
Listening for audio...
Recognized: வெல்கம்.
```

[image]